# How to implement a form validation/error handling function in Node/Express to count number of checkboxes ticked

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, validation

I have a form on an .EJS page and it has multiple checkboxes. I'm trying to set a validator for checkboxes with a certain name='' to have a set amount of checks allowed.

```
// this is the app.js
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const path = require('path');
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    
    
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    
    const dbUrl = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/workoutapp';
    // const dbUrl = process.env.DB_URL ||
    
    mongoose.connect(dbUrl, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });
    
    const Workout = require('./models/workout');
    const Week = require('./models/week');
          
    
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.render('home')
    })
    app.get('/freq', (req, res) => {
        res.render('freq')
    })
    app.post('/freq', async (req, res) => {
        const { schedule } = req.body
    
        if (schedule === 'threeX') {
            const week = new Week({
                name: 'threeX',
                day1: 'Full body',
                day2: 'Rest',
                day3: 'Full body',
                day4: 'Rest',
                day5: 'Full body',
                day6: 'Rest',
                day7: 'Rest'
            });
            await week.save()
            res.redirect(`/threeX/?week=${week._id}`)
        }
        else if (schedule === 'fourX') {
            const week = new Week({
                name: 'fourX',
                day1: 'Upper',
                day2: 'Lower',
                day3: 'Rest',
                day4: 'Upper',
                day5: 'Lower',
                day6: 'Rest',
                day7: 'Rest'
            });
            await week.save()
    
            res.redirect(`/fourX/?week=${week._id}`)
        }
        else if (schedule === 'sixX') {
            const week = new Week({
                name: 'sixX',
                day1: 'Push',
                day2: 'Pull',
                day3: 'Legs',
                day4: 'Push',
                day5: 'Pull',
                day6: 'Legs',
                day7: 'Rest'
            });
            await week.save()
            res.redirect(`/sixX/?week=${week._id}`)
        }
    })
    
    app.get('/threeX/', (req, res) => {
        const { week } = req.query
        res.render('threeX', { week })
    })
    
    app.get('/fourX/', (req, res) => {
        const { week } = req.query
        res.render('fourX', { week })
    })
    app.get('/sixX/', (req, res) => {
        const { week } = req.query
        res.render('sixX', { week })
    })
    
    app.post('/print/', async (req, res) => {
        const newWorkout = new Workout(req.body);
        await newWorkout.save()
        const weekLayout = req.body.weekId
        res.redirect(`/print/${newWorkout._id}/${weekLayout}`)
    })
    
    app.get('/print/:workoutId/:weekId', async (req, res) => {
        const { workoutId } = req.params;
        const { weekId } = req.params;
        const workout = await Workout.findById(workoutId);
        const weekLayout = await Week.findById(weekId);
        res.render('print', { workout, weekLayout })
    })
    
    
    app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log('Connected on port 3000.')
    })




// this is one of the .ejs files
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Full Body</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Full Body 3x/Week</h1>

    <form action="/print" method="POST">
        <h3>Full Body Programming</h3>
        <input type="hidden" name="weekId" id="" value="<%=week%>">

        <span>Main leg exercise: (pick one)</span>
        <label for="squat">Back squat</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="legsMain" id="squat" value="Back squat">
        <br>
        <hr>
        <span>Main chest exercise: (pick one)</span>
        <label for="flatBench">Flat bench press</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chestMain" id="flatBench" value="Flat bench press">
        <label for="incBench">Incline bench press</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chestMain" id="incBench" value="Incline bench press">
        <label for="flatDB">Flat dumbbell press</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chestMain" id="flatDB" value="Flat dumbbell press">
        <label for="incDB">Incline dumbbell press</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chestMain" id="incDB" value="Incline dumbbell press">
        <br>
        <hr>
        <span>Main back exercise: (pick one)</span>
        <label for="bbRow">Bentover barbell row</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="backMain" id="bbRow" value="Bentover barbell row">
        <label for="machineRow">Machine row</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="backMain" id="machineRow" value="Machine row">
        <br>
        <hr>
        <span>Main shoulder exercise: (pick one)</span>
        <label for="ohp">Barbell overhead press</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="shoulderMain" id="ohp" value="Barbell overhead press">
        <label for="seatedPress">Seated shoulder press</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="shoulderMain" id="seatedPress" value="Seated shoulder press">
        <br>
        <hr>
        <span>Secondary legs exercise: (pick one)</span>
        <label for="legPress">Leg press</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="legsSecond" id="legPress" value="Leg press">
        <label for="deadlift">Deadlift</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="legsSecond" id="deadlift" value="Deadlift">
        <br>
        <hr>
        <span>Secondary chest exercise: (pick one)</span>
        <br>
        <label for="flatBench2">Flat bench press (if not selected for main chest exercise)</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chestSecond" id="flatBench2" value="Flat bench press">
        <br>
        <label for="incBench2">Incline bench press (if not selected for main chest exercise)</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chestSecond" id="incBench2" value="Incline bench press">
        <br>
        <label for="flatDB2">Flat dumbbell press (if not selected for main chest exercise)</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chestSecond" id="flatDB2" value="Flat dumbbell press">
        <br>
        <label for="incDB2">Incline dumbbell press (if not selected for main chest exercise)</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chestSecond" id="incDB2" value="Incline dumbbell press">
        <br>
        <label for="cgbp">Close grip bench press</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chestSecond" id="cgbp" value="Close grip bench press">
        <br>
        <hr>
        <span>Secondary back exercise: (pick one)</span>
        <label for="pullups">Pullups</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="backSecond" id="pullups" value="Pullups">
        <label for="LatPulldown">Lat pulldown</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="backSecond" id="LatPulldown" value="Lat pulldown">
        <label for="chinups">Chinups</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="backSecond" id="chinups" value="Chinups">
        <br>
        <hr>
        <span>Accessory exercise: (pick two)</span>
        <label for="dbFly">Dumbbell fly</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="accessory" id="dbFly" value="Dumbbell fly">
        <label for="legEx">Leg extension</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="accessory" id="legEx" value="Leg extension">
        <label for="legCurl">Leg curl</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="accessory" id="legCurl" value="Leg curl">
        <label for="lateral">Lateral raises</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="accessory" id="lateral" value="Lateral raises">
        <label for="seatRow">Seated row</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="accessory" id="seatRow" value="Seated row">
        <label for="dbRow">Dumbbell row</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="accessory" id="dbRow" value="Dumbbell row">
        <label for="bbCurl">Barbell curl</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="accessory" id="bbCurl" value="Barbell curl">
        <label for="skullCrush">Skull crusher</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="accessory" id="skullCrush" value="Skull crusher">
        <br>
        <hr>



        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

The name of the form input is chestMain. The function validateForm currently only works for if 1 box is checked. if I take off the split() then it works for 2+ boxes checked. I know there must be a better way to do this I feel like I'm using a janky method.

As you can see I'm trying to get the number of boxes checked from my post route and I need to display a frontend message to tell the user to only check a certain amount of boxes.

Comment: It's unclear if the validation is for one or multiple checkboxes that meet the "name" criteria, I would suggest that you clarify your first statement. 

Also, the source code doesn't seem to match the second part of your question. I would suggest that you try to post your latest working code as-is.

Comment: @MauricioMorales The validation is for all the checkboxes with a same name. I editted my post with all the original code.